# Angular-like framework for Node.Js based on express.js that could easily do sorting / filtering.

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, express

Anybody can recommend an easy-to-use framework for Node.Js (like Angular, but something lighter, also based on Express.Js) that enables basic filtering / sorting features without reloading the page (route)?

Or shall I just do it manually through JQuery?

What I have is a list on short text snippets on the left and a tag cloud on the right. When a user clicks on a tag, I want only those text snippets to show, which contain the tag. I might also later have to query them from the database on every click (for other data), just to give you an idea.

Thank you!

PS tried looking but didn't find anything that would just be very light and easy.

Comment: Btw, Angular is **not** "based on Express.Js".

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Node.js/Express related. You are looking for a client-side solution. So if Angular is too heavy for you, maybe take a look at Backbone.js which has backend communication built in, or something even smaller? But to get a real answer here, please show us some code of what you have now, and then somebody could help you make it more efficient.

Comment: @Stewie sorry I'm just a beginner in that stuff )

Comment: @Zlatko I need a Node.Js module that would handle filtering and sorting the data displayed, so it is Node.Js related. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, if you show (simplified) your two data structures used on the server - tags and text - and how you handle indexing, I'll try to help you with a filter function on the server.
If you already have that data on the client, I can try help you there too. But you should show some code - I can't work with nothing.